# skypeforlinux Ubuntu package says File has unexpected size (2471 != 2457). Mirror sync in Progress?

Tags: skype, ubuntu-mate

When I am running apt get update in Ubuntu mate 18.04 the following things happens

```
Err:10 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages                   
File has unexpected size (2248 != 2481). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 104.89.123.202 443]
Hashes of expected file:
 - Filesize:2481 [weak]
 - SHA512:97a1cc8c9c71d68e35b37c9ef33a85859bbabb482b482a71c70d657cc9464210fce0a1afda11dd5c8275071b60291324dac9b0a39979542cef326a14e09be5fc
 - SHA256:27a18eb994515c58706b3516b1430d5cdb4a3030fc95fc4c17a6e712f00f808b
 - SHA1:8dedefb9caea4b2f69fac16419494805e8c87a76 [weak]
 - MD5Sum:67e1b981d511902b109dc6bfd54ce30d [weak]
Release file created at: Mon, 24 Sep 2018 12:21:19 +0000
```

And the following when reading the packages.

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2  File has unexpected size (2471 != 2457). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 23.58.225.224 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:2457 [weak]
    - SHA512:58f0d8f3255a5cc7f28a3a1270ff655e187c9cae212391a570b6c3512c20852549a0f706c9df7ccd1be7cc3ce791547c2c6dcdf44021425756c1d824995be14a
    - SHA256:bcd5e58ed12bf52cd8a16d947b9209f4292d339dc11898f8ebe501106b5dc311
    - SHA1:d534917678932e9320d80da96c4f1b2c6dbf478c [weak]
    - MD5Sum:2a9e2b845f1b29d8ee10ec10de46686d [weak]
   Release file created at: Mon, 24 Sep 2018 11:56:19 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

From here I can see the problem is in skypeforlinux package, but I can't find a way to solve it.

Comment: The problem seems transitory and is gone now. Everything is as before.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the skype repository list using worked for me:

```
rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list*
```

It was automatically installed when unpacking official deb obtained from [https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/). You don't need to remove skype application though.

Comment: Not a good suggestion, you won't get updates of Skype automatically any more.